# Can I run a flutter app on my physical Iphone 7, that is connected to my Windows desktop pc?

Tags: ios, windows, macos, android-studio, flutter

I have installed flutter and I spent some time making sure that the command:

```
flutter doctor
```

doesn't report anymore warnings. However, there is one warning I cannot get rid off, and that is the "no devices available" warning. I have an Iphone 7 that is physically connected to my desktop through a USB-cable, and Itunes even recognizes the Iphone.

I saw some posts about Xcode, which unfortunately only is available on Mac, but my question essentially boils down to whether or not I can test my flutter applications on my own physical Iphone connected to my windows desktop pc or if I will need to buy a Mac computer and install Xcode to do so. Does anyone know?

Comment: i think there is multi ways for doing these